# How to chain returns in nodejs with ioredis?

Tags: javascript, node.js, redis, node-redis

I'm using [ioredis](https://github.com/luin/ioredis) and I would like to return the path and value in the example below all the way up to the anonymous function.

```
console.log(
    function (jsonGraphArg) {
        return Redis.hget(jsonGraphArg[0], jsonGraphArg[1], function(error, result){
             result = JSON.parse(result);
             return {
                 path: [jsonGraphArg[0], jsonGraphArg[1], jsonGraphArg[2][0]],
                 value: result[jsonGraphArg[2][0]]
             };
        });
    }
);
```

I would expect the outcome to be something like this in the `console.log()`:

```
{
    path: "something",
    value: "something else"
}
```

But instead it gives me:

```
{
  _bitField: 1,
  _fulfillmentHandler0: [Function: successAdapter],
  _rejectionHandler0: [Function: errorAdapter],
  _progressHandler0: undefined,
  _promise0: [Function],
  _receiver0: [Circular],
  _settledValue: undefined
}
```

Answer (score 1):

First of all you are trying to log function declaration instead of function execution results.

```
console.log(
    (function (jsonGraphArg) {
        return Redis.hget(jsonGraphArg[0], jsonGraphArg[1], function(error, result){
             result = JSON.parse(result);
             return {
                 path: [jsonGraphArg[0], jsonGraphArg[1], jsonGraphArg[2][0]],
                 value: result[jsonGraphArg[2][0]]
             };
        });
    })();
);
```

This code will get you a result of function execution.

Second problem is that `Redis.hget` is an asynchronous function. To get results as soon as redis returns them you need to use a callback.

```
var callback = function(res) {
    console.log(res);
}

(function (jsonGraphArg, callback) {
    return Redis.hget(jsonGraphArg[0], jsonGraphArg[1], function(error, result){
         result = JSON.parse(result);
         return callback({
             path: [jsonGraphArg[0], jsonGraphArg[1], jsonGraphArg[2][0]],
             value: result[jsonGraphArg[2][0]]
         });
    });
})();
```

With this code when redis returns data it will call `callback` function with `res` argument which will be your object with path and value properties.

Comment: Thanks for the tip, my answer was in a then() promis though :-)

Answer (score 0):

The answer was in the promis

```
console.log(
    function (jsonGraphArg) {
        return Redis.hget(jsonGraphArg[0], jsonGraphArg[1]).
        then(function(result){
             result = JSON.parse(result);
             return {
                 path: [jsonGraphArg[0], jsonGraphArg[1], jsonGraphArg[2][0]],
                 value: result[jsonGraphArg[2][0]]
             };
        });
    }
);
```